# How to determine the length of unique values by grouping 2 columns in r

Tags: r, count, unique

I am trying to conditionally extract the number of unique values based on 2 columns. What I want to do is save the length of unique observations when considering both the "variable" and "Date" and save each unique observation as a list so I can run each observation through a loop. Below is a subset of the dataframe and the code I've been running. There should be 9 unique observations in both ncurves and ids. I'm getting 2 in ncurves and ids is saving as a dataframe and not a list to be run through a loop like I want.

```
a <- structure(list(LightIntensity = c(0L, 112L, 0L, 112L, 0L, 112L, 0L, 112L, 0L, 112L, 0L, 
112L, 0L, 112L, 0L, 112L, 0L, 112L), variable = c(221L, 221L, 244L, 244L, 12L, 12L, 221L, 
221L, 244L, 244L, 12L, 12L, 221L, 221L, 12L, 12L, 244L, 244L), value = c(-1.21625718690742, 
0.192572605693232, -1.21625718690742, 0.226570039268424, -0.437571128774482, 
0.167029555798728, -0.344666861319387, -0.099033581577414, -0.341605586260893, 
0.158985219436985, -0.0728378731631007, 0.108468868197142, -0.227259158534414, 
-0.121668829961881, -0.504828403085384, 0.37919920958843, -0.674980508632225, 
0.215847519075345), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Montipora capitata", "Porites compressa"), class = 
"factor"), Bleach = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Bleach", "Non-bleach"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2019-09-16", 
"2019-10-02", "2019-10-16"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 28L, 29L, 181L, 182L, 361L, 362L, 481L, 482L, 541L, 542L, 761L, 762L, 891L, 892L, 921L, 
922L), class = "data.frame")

n <- length(unique(a[c("variable", "Date")]))
ids <- unique(a[c("variable", "Date")])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the unique combinations in a data.frame you can do:

```
a[!duplicated(a[c("variable", "Date")]),]

    LightIntensity variable       value            Species     Bleach       Date
1                0      221 -1.21625719 Montipora capitata     Bleach 2019-09-16
28               0      244 -1.21625719  Porites compressa Non-bleach 2019-09-16
181              0       12 -0.43757113 Montipora capitata Non-bleach 2019-09-16
361              0      221 -0.34466686 Montipora capitata     Bleach 2019-10-02
481              0      244 -0.34160559  Porites compressa Non-bleach 2019-10-02
541              0       12 -0.07283787 Montipora capitata Non-bleach 2019-10-02
761              0      221 -0.22725916 Montipora capitata     Bleach 2019-10-16
891              0       12 -0.50482840 Montipora capitata Non-bleach 2019-10-16
921              0      244 -0.67498051  Porites compressa Non-bleach 2019-10-16
```

To get an index you can do:

```
(ids <- which(!duplicated(a[c("variable", "Date")])))
[1]  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17

length(ids)
[1] 9
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change `length` to `nrow` you will get 9 unique observations instead of 2:

```
n <- nrow(unique(a[c("variable", "Date")]))
```

And with `split` you can create a list out of the dataframe.

```
ids <- split(unique(a[c("variable", "Date")]), seq_len(n))
```